# Which shield component modifies which shield stat(s)?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been reading the [Borderlands 2 Wiki's "Shield" article](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shield#Borderlands_2) to create my own shields through Gibbed's Save Editor. I've learned that shields have the following parts: Body, Battery, Capacitor (each could be made by a different manufacturer) and that they modify the following stats: Recharge Delay, Recharge Rate, Special 01 and Special 02. With a few exceptions, the body, battery, and capacitor are interchangeable on a shield. Shields also have a separate "Manufacturer" property (shown in-game) separate from the above-mentioned parts.

Since [some shield component manufacturers have a better stat modifier of certain components](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:DamianDavis/Shield_Parts_%28Borderlands_2%29), and to create the best shield for my character through Gibbed's Save Editor, I would like to know which shield component modifies which stat(s).

Editing shield components in Gibbed's Save Editor:
[image: Editing shield components in Gibbed's Save Editor]

Answer (score 1):

[Gear calculator](http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/)

You need move the mouse cursor to part name (body for example) and you'll see what stat is improved (green) and what will get worse (red).
Also, you can see final result ("calculate" button).

[image]

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding the relevant information from the linked site, to prevent link rot.